# Top application menu missing links after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: 17.10, menu-bar

Recently after upgrading to ubuntu 17.10 the top application menu is missing most of its links:

[image]

This is happening for all applications, a few may have more links in the dropdown like terminal, most just show **Quit**.

For Firefox, I can choose "**Menu Bar**" to be shown like this:

[image]

but that is not what I want.

I want it to be shown like it used to be:

[image]